# Flutter build self-made map

Tags: flutter

I want to build a custom map from a country e.g. United States and when tapping on a state or moving over it I want to display custom data e.g. size of the state on it.
How would that be possible? Is there a way to display a self-made map in Flutter and make the states something like a button? How can the map be made?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what do you mean by a self-made map, but in general for the moment in flutter you can display a map using rather google maps which is paid. or flutter_map plugin which is for free.

for google maps in the web clickable regions is easy and  i think for flutter will be the same .

in order to have clickable state i propose 2 methods that can work for you on both google maps and flutter_map :

1. put transparent buttons on the state so that  when the user click on a  state he clicks actually on one of the transparent buttons of the state but this method will force you to limit the zoom level low in order to cover all the state with few buttons .
2. use on-click(on ta) method of the map that returns the latitude and longitude of the place you tapped on. after getting the (lat,long) you have to use it to get the country name and this can be done using a Geo-coding api like

OpenStretMap Nominatime:

https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/

or Opencage

https://opencagedata.com/

Comment: Hi Khalil, thanks for your answer. By self-made map I meant something like that https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Deutschlandkarte_(Bunt).svg . Thats Germany for example and I want to make each state clickable and show some Information on it. I could just use the image and put buttons on it but don't now if that's the best solution.